# Radio Buttons within Group box confirm on is selected before code continues

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to C# and visual studio however have a problem.

I have 10 Radio buttons within one group box. I need to confirm one of these radio buttons is selected before continuing the code. And if one is not selected then a message box pop-up to ask user to select a radio button.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: use some front end validation dude..

Comment: Share code you've tried

Comment: I suggest you help yourself first, and *then* we can help you with whatever specific problem you're having with your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in two ways.

The first way is the `back-end validation`. I.e., after the form is submitted.

**Eg:**

```
if(FormModel.RadioButton != null || FormModel.RadioButton != "") 
//this can be used(For MVC in the Action Method)
```

The second way is, the `client-side/Front-end validation(JavaScript validation)`.

**eg:**

```
<script language="javascript">
   function ClientValidate() //To be called during submit button-click
   {
        if ($('#RadioButton1').checked //Where RadioButton1 is the Id of the first element
            || $('#RadioButton2').checked ) {
            arguments.IsValid = true;
        } else {
            arguments.IsValid = false;
        }
   }
</script>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: I was more think of:
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         If GroupBox1.Radiobuttons(Radiobutton1, Radiobutton2).checked = False
Then MessageBox "Please Select a RadioButton"
Else //Continue Code
        }

Comment: its like you check only when these buttons are clicked which does not hold good during validation.

Comment: btw is the button 1 the submit button?

Comment: Yes so select a radio button and press button. Then upon button press check at least one radio button within groupbox1 is checked.

Comment: have a look at [this link](https://forums.asp.net/t/1199803.aspx?how+to+validate+a+group+of+radio+buttons+).

Comment: Are perfect, worked it out:
if (Group_box.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Any(r => r.Checked))
Else 
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Client Data Not Present", "Process not working", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);